# How to get replica number of an elasticserach cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a Elasticsearch instance running on AWS. Below is the cluster health data:

```
{
  "cluster_name": "553479592532:test-perf",
  "status": "yellow",
  "timed_out": false,
  "number_of_nodes": 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes": 1,
  "active_primary_shards": 6,
  "active_shards": 6,
  "relocating_shards": 0,
  "initializing_shards": 0,
  "unassigned_shards": 5,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis": 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number": 54.54545454545454
}
```

From the above output, I can see that there are 1 node and 6 shards. 6 shards have been assigned to the node and there are 5 unassigned shards. But how can I know the number of replicas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the indices api, which would list all the indices in your cluster and their primary and replica shards. As your number of primary shards are already small, hence you won't even get the huge number of indices in your cluster.

API := http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v, here replace localhost with your elastic host.

Edit: Response provide by OP is from [cluster health API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html) , and according to docs, And according to official ES docs:

> active_primary_shards(integer): The number of active primary shards.
>
> active_shards(integer): The total number of active primary and replica
>   shards.

I also tested this locally and it works fine, by looking at `active_shards`, **its clear that you don't have any replica shards.**. You can basically subtract the value of `active_primary_shards` from `active_shards`.

Comment: I know I can view indices. My question is how I can find the number of replicas?

Comment: @ZhaoYi, updated my answer, I knew its difficult to count the no of replica shards based on indices, but looks like cluster health API provides this option.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Can two primary shards exist in one node?

Comment: Yes, multiple primary shards can exist on one node. But Elasticsearch won't allocate replica shards on the same node. So if you only have a single (data) node, your replica shards will never be created.